# Combining low poly cone and disc

Tags: mesh, topology

I have these two low poly objects (cone and disc) that I would like to combine into a single mesh while still maintaining somewhat low poly count and good topology. Is there a simple way to do this? If not, can you suggest a method to achieve this? Boolean union will create erratic polygon topology.

[image]

Comment: What would the disadvantages for you in keeping it as it is? You cannot perform cuts without increasing the polycount in this case. Could you be more precise about what your target is, a bit of background ?It would be easier to suggest you a modeling advices.

Comment: The best way is to use Boolean, then connect the vertices in order to get rid of the Ngons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I for myself always try to connect objects in "a clean way" whenever possible but there are many cases where objects just won't fit in a way that justifies the effort for the sake of that rule.

While you can certainly split your geometry on both objects it's not the best thing to do here, because

1. you will increase your vertex count unnecessarily nonetheless
2. your topology won't get cleaner.

In the case of your model I'd just keep the objects as they are. If however you still want them to be connected I would rotate the disk so that the cone meets a flat part of the disk's edge and then rotate the cone so that the loop cut of the disk hits one of the cone's edges. It then should be at least a little easier to connect both pieces.